# Jquery Facebook button wont show

Tags: jquery, html, css

i try to integrate a facebook button which will shown up after i hover a div so everything works fine but the button will not shown up

ok my english isnt well so im a little confused cause i read that i need to parse this element but how to go ?

jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
$("#f_button").hide(); 
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#f_box").mouseover(function() {
$('#f_button').css('display','block');
$("#f_wing").hide();
}); 
$("#f_box").mouseout(function() {
$('#f_button').css('display','none');

$("#f_wing").show();
});
});
</script>
```

html

```
<div id="f_box">
<div id="f_wing">
text
</div>
<div id="f_button">
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/xx" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
text
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#f_box
{
height: 70px;
width: 70px;
background-color: blue;
margin-top: 250px;
position: fixed;
}

#f_wing
{
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: white;
}

#f_button
{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
display: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
background-color: red;
}
```

## edit

now this is how it looks like now

//so the idea behind with ajax/jquery is that i need to reload the button on jquery ??

Comment: are you using some facebook button generated by the fb-site???

Comment: yes i used the facebook button generated by fb and no it runs on a live server so i didnt know why it wont work -  if i remove the display none it will show normal

Answer (score 0):

Happened with me a while back...do 2 things and it works 99% times :

- make sure you are running your website from some server may be a `localhost` and not directly browser
- ensure that there are no plugins blocking the visibility of the fb button (*certain pop-up blocker plugins do that*)

**Edit**

You have set `display:none` on `#f_button`, so even on hover that display type is set on the `f_button` and hence it does not appear.... change display type of the `#f_button` on mouse hover like :

```
$('#f_button').css('display','block');
```

instead of

```
$("#f_button").show();
```

this should do!!

**2nd edit**

after you call the jQuery lib, use the following to trigger `hide()` even before the DOM is ready

```
$(function(){
    $("#f_button").hide(); 
});
```

This way, by using the below method, you can trigger any method as many time as you want....

```
$(function(){
    //code to do some action before the DOM is ready
});
```

Comment: ok it helps to change show and hide into css display so one step further - only problem wenn page is loading it will show first the button - i tried to edit the document ready function maybe there is a solution where i can set up something like     $(document).ready(function("#f_button").hide - is this possible ?

Comment: simple and very stupid actually,do => `("#f_button").hide()` just after jquery file inclusion and outside `$(document).ready(function())`...so it wont wait for DOM to get ready and execute the line first!! :)

Comment: sure outside of the document ready function but with simple  <script type="text/javascript">

$("#f_button").hide();

</script> wont help i need a event like startup or onload or something

Comment: good idea but still wont work - if i set with '$(function(){
    $("#f_button").hide(); 
});' it doesnt make any change hover it - its totally hide

Comment: `display: none;` should not show the `f_box` by default nywhere....you getting the flicker in that,right???

Comment: i removed display: none after adding  $("#f_box").mouseout(function() {
  $('#f_button').css('display','none'); so it works until the first view onload the page

Comment: no no..keep the `display:none` in the css....jquery will overwrite it once mouse-hover is triggered...you will see the `button` then....

Comment: edit my question this is how it looks now and same problem - the container wont load the button after hide it and run event //edit funny thing in opera and ie it works in ff not -.-

Comment: i can not see the button at all.....the left of the page has that `fixed div` which shows `text`...

Answer (score 0):

If the style is set to `display:none` on page load, the button won't render. Happened the same to me two days ago.

So, what you need to do is find a way of "hiding" the button on load, and what I did was

```
#f_button.isLoading {
    position:fixed;
    top:-50px;
    left:-50px;
}
```

And, on load, just remove the class, instead of performing a `.show()`

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear, but I will try my best to answer (because I can't comment, <46 rep).

1. If you are **running off file:// URIs**, Facebook buttons **won't work**. Try something like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
2. If it still does not work, maybe you have forgotten something:

   1. Check that you have set up the required tags properly. (The **`<div id="fb-root"></div>`** and the `<script>(function(d, s, id) {...` tags should be done [accordingly](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/). )
   2. Check the console for errors.
   3. I'm sure your HTML syntax is valid.
3. Test out Nico's fix. It may also be because the iframe Facebook injects hasn't load.
4. **Not tried:** Maybe your app is in sandboxed mode or are you blocking certain urls in the app dashboard?
5. **Not tried:** Try using the iframe instead.
6. *Still not working?* It seems to work for me: [codepen](http://codepen.io/ambc/pen/FpCgB)

Note:

- jQuery `.show()` is equivalent to `.css("display", "block")` just that it is returned to initial display state (i.e. "inline-block", "block" or "inline") instead of "block".
- I tried the iframe but removed the &appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx URL parameter still seems to work... weird.